# How to add labels to SOME nodes in my network

Tags: r, igraph

I am trying to create a two-mode network in which I want to add labels to the one mode of nodes. My data looks like: (See end of post)

I cannot use the name as a substitute, as some of the data I am working with does not have unique names, only ID numbers. And I am using iGraph

I have tried few different things, the closest I can come is the following:

```
Test <- read_delim("Test.csv", ";", escape_double = FALSE, 
                   col_names = FALSE, trim_ws = TRUE)


df <- Test %>% select(Mode1, Mode2) 
g <- graph.edgelist(as.matrix(df, directed = F)

g <- set_vertex_attr(g, "name", index = V(g), as.character(Test$Name))
```

I hoped that this would allow me to write:

```
plot(g, vertex.label = V(g)$name)
```

and have the names come up as labels,
but instead I get an error message when writing:

```
g <- set_vertex_attr(g, "name", index = V(g), as.character(Test$Name))
```

saying :

```
In vattrs[[name]][index] <- value :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
```

Data:

```
Test <- structure(list(Mode1 = c("1", "1", "1", "2", "2", "2", "2", "3", 
"3", "3"), Mode2 = c("11", "12", "13", "14", "12", "16", "17", 
"18", "29", "11"), Name = c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", 
"C", "C", "C")), .Names = c("Mode1", "Mode2", "Name"), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -10L), spec = structure(list(
    cols = structure(list(Mode1 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), Mode2 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), Name = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector"))), .Names = c("Mode1", "Mode2", "Name")), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
    "collector"))), .Names = c("cols", "default"), class = "col_spec"))
```

Comment: The way that you create your graph now, many disconnected nodes are created. Did you mean that (for example, did you mean to have a nodes named 8 and 25) or did you only want the nodes mentioned in the edgelist?  Also, you had the numbers consecutively from 11 to 18 and that is followed by 29.  Did you mean 29 or did you mean 19?  Do you want to label mode 1 or Mode 2?

Comment: Ah, I changed the data now, so now i should make more sense. And I want to have to the names on Mode1

Comment: Improved. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this is what you want. `set_vertex_attr` needs one value per node. So I initialize all values of name to NA, then change just the Mode1 nodes to the right name.

```
Mode1Nodes = as.numeric(unique(df$Mode1))
Mode1Names = as.character(aggregate(Test$Name, list(Test$Mode1), FUN=head, 1)$x)

g <- set_vertex_attr(g, "name", index = V(g), NA)
g <- set_vertex_attr(g, "name", index = V(g)[Mode1Nodes], value=Mode1Names)
plot(g)
```

[image: Graph with only Mode 1 nodes labeled]

Comment: Yeeeees! Thank you so much!